# How do I repair a corroded water supply pipe under the sink?

Tags: plumbing

My bathroom sink cold water supply line (that comes out of the wall) is corroded through and dripping just before where the shut off valve is connected. Its hard to tell if the corroded line is copper or galvanized. There's so much corrosion build up it's hard to tell. Since there's rust, I believe it to be galvanized. A lot of white corrosion along with red rust. The house is 1962 and it seems like original pipe. Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to the trunk lines in the basement? I'd be looking to strip as much of the galvanized as possible and replacing it with pex or copper. Not too expensive, not too difficult.

Comment: Limited access. laundry room is directly below with drop ceiling

Comment: Hopefully, I can get a picture uploaded soon..

Comment: Have you looked around there? The answer depends on how far you're willing to take the project. Galvanized only gets worse, so go as far as you can.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Okay, correction.. I broke away a portion of the drywall or plaster and it is copper supply line and in good shape. It comes up from the basement and where it 90's out of the wall, I can't tell if the "90" fitting is copper or otherwise. If I can get a wrench in there, I hopefully can unscrew the corroded nipple piece from the 90 but not sure if it's soldered or screwed in. Is it common to have a cast iron or galvanized 90 connected to copper supply line?

Comment: Not in my experience, but possible. I'd probably remove the elbow and either sweat on a new 90 or use a Shark Bite fitting to allow you to run new copper.